# Flutter - sending complex JSON to server

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am developing a shopping App on flutter where I have to send user info along with the list of items in cart to server. I searched over internet all the day and couldn't find solution that works for me. JSON that I have to submit, looks like the following.

```
{
"areaId": 9,
"userId": 4,
"totalOrder": [{
    "categoryId": "1",
    "itemId": "1",
    "priceOfItem": 28,
    "serviceTypeId": 1,
    "title": "Shalwar Kameez"
}, {
    "categoryId": "1",
    "itemId": "2",
    "priceOfItem": 28,
    "serviceTypeId": 1,
    "title": "Shalwar Kameez Ladies (2Pcs)"
}, {
    "categoryId": "1",
    "itemId": "2",
    "priceOfItem": 28,
    "serviceTypeId": 1,
    "title": "Shalwar Kameez Ladies (2Pcs)"
 }]
}
```

The way I am sending data to server is following.

```
 Future<String> saveOrder() async {
   var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();

   map["userId"] = await SharedPreferencesUser.getUserId();
   map["areaId"] = await SharedPreferencesUser.getAreaId();
   map["totalOrder"] = cart.items; // this is list of items in cart List<CartItem> 

   var res = await http.post(
   Uri.encodeFull(Url.url + Apis.saveOrder),
   headers: {"Accept": "application/json"},
   body: json.encode(map), //encoding to json
   );

  return res.body;
}
```

The Exception I am receiving is 
"Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'CartItem'"

CartItem class looks like this

```
class CartItem {
  String id;
  String categoryId;
  String itemName;
  int piece;
  int price;
  int quantity;
  String serviceType;
  String serviceId;
  String defalutCategory;

  CartItem(this.id, this.categoryId, this.itemName, this.piece, this.price,
      this.quantity, {this.serviceType, this.serviceId, this.defalutCategory});
}
```

Kindly help me sorting this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to encode a List which contains an object. When encode is called on an object, it will try calling the method `toJson()`. If this method is not implemented, `json.encode` will fail.

Try adding this to your `CartItem` class:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>  {
    'id': id,
    'categoryId': categoryId,
    'itemName': itemName,
    'piece': piece,
    'price': price,
    'quantity': quantity,
    'serviceType': serviceType,
    'serviceId': serviceId,
    'defaultCategory': defaultCategory,
  };
```

also you spelled `defaultCategory` wrong so I changed it in my answer from `defalutCategory`

Comment: I am trying it but where should I call this method ?